# Remove npm module "reload"

Tags: npm, ubuntu-14.04

asking for help. Using Ubuntu 14.04.

Yesterday i've tried to configure my "auto-reload" for node.js. I've used supervisor + reload.
All was ok. But at some of the reboots started lagging terribly. 
At the moment i've figured, that i have 2 proccesses called "node" they both point to this "reload".

```
node /usr/bin/reload smbd
node /usr/bin/reload cups
```

And eating 1.6gb ram each. Cpu load for them also is coming up to 25%.
I cannot turn them of from the system monitor (dunno why, they reload back or?).
I've done so far:

```
npm remove -g reload
```

But as I understand this only removes the global link.

My googling proccess now is very slow, asking for any help here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. There are two similar options in the proccess list context menu, but they act different.

Not sure how correctly in English (I have russian version) must be something like:

- Close proccess - this did nothing
- Take off process - and this  closed

After reboot they didn't show up, so the problem is solved.